# Adding an IF AND THEN Statement in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create an IF AND THEN statement in my vba.  I've tried this code below and although I get no errors it doesn't work (ie: nothing happens when I run the macro):

```
Sub PrintAll()

  Dim BrokerCell As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Wks As Worksheet

Set Wks = Worksheets("PRINT PAGE")

 If Range("$A$5").Value = "Company 1" Then
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company1").RefersToRange
 ElseIf Range("$A$5").Value = "Company2" Then
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company2").RefersToRange
 Else: Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company3").RefersToRange
 End If

  For Each BrokerCell In Rng
    If BrokerCell <> "" AND "$Q$5" > "0" Then
       Wks.Range("$B$5").Value = BrokerCell.Text
       Wks.PrintOut
    End If
  Next BrokerCell

End Sub
```

The macro works without the

```
 AND "$Q$5" > "0"
```

so clearly I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru the code using the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
If BrokerCell <> "" And Range("$Q$5").Value > 0
```

You're comparing the literal string "$Q$5" to the literal string "0".

Comment: This is definitely pointing me in the right direction, but the macro is printing all the iterations in the loop instead of just those where the Q5 cell value is greater than zero.

Comment: But surely Q5 is either greater than 0 or it isn't. So if Q5 = 0 then the loop will never run and if it is greater than 0 it will only loop where `BrokerCell <> ""`.

Comment: Maybe move the line `Wks.Range("$B$5").Value = BrokerCell.Text` to right above the `If` statement?

Comment: The issue was with the look ups that I have on the excel page itself - all Q5 results were less than or equal to zero, hence no print outs.  The macro is working perfectly now.  Thank you!!